# Django redirect and break current flow

Tags: python, django, redirect, request

I have a piece of code that needs to redirect the user on some condition and continue the normal flow if not:

```
# entry point of the request
def MyView(request):
  object = MyAuth(request)
  # do stuff with object

  return render('some_template.html')


def MyAuth(request):
   if some_condition is True:
      return redirect('url')

    return object
```

But it seems that the redirect does not occurs, as I have the template rendered each time.

Why won't the redirect break the current flow?

I tried to add some tests and change the flow of the methods, but I still don't understand why the redirect would not stop the current request.

Comment: Whatever you return from `MyAuth(request)` is getting stored in the `object` which in turn is not being returned at all.

Comment: OK, if I do not return my redirect statement, will it be executed instead ?

Comment: Instead of returning a response from `MyAuth` you could throw an exception and catch it in `MyView` and then redirect to the url. If you don't need to reuse `MyAuth` I would suggest write everything in `MyView` only.

Comment: The usage is a little bit more complex, actually I managed to get it running by returning the url for the redirect along with a True/False value, si I check the validity and redirect if needed, but that seems too much ...

Comment: I assume you know the `type` of the `object`. So you could write a condition to check if the `object` is an instance of `HttpResponseRedirect` or not and return it if it is a redirect.

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended doing, but I didn't wanted to move the redirect out of `MyAuth`

Comment: I added what I suggested as an answer because I wasn't able to explain it properly in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the type of `object` and return accordingly (*this answer is followed by the discussion in comments above*).

```
def MyView(request):
   object = MyAuth(request)

   # if it is a redirect then return it.
   if isinstance(object, HttpResponseRedirect):
       return object

   # do stuff with object

   return render('some_template.html')
```

Comment: Please also add relevant comment when you downvote the answer.

Comment: Event if it is working I find it rather confusing as MyAuth will return different types of objects. If MyAuth always redirect to the same url when a condition is matched then simply return None in MyAuth, check the value of the returned object in MyView and if it is None redirect to the url.

Comment: That's a good point. However, I added this answer because you were quite adamant on changing the implementation of `MyAuth` because if you look at my comments from yesterday I also suggested that if your condition is not met you could throw an exception and catch it in `MyView`. What I am trying to say is that there are multiple ways you could have done this. The answer here only took into account your current implementation with minimum change possible. And as I suggested earlier, if you just need to check the condition you could do all that in `MyView` only.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that *you* wrote the comment suggesting exception handling... By the way I'm not the author of the post :-)

Comment: Ohh.. I am so sorry. There is so much `MyAuth` and `MyView` that I read `My` in between the lines. But still I stick to my comment _(though not directed to you personally)_.